# Setting up translation in Django - Makemessages doesn't create a file

Tags: django, windows, translation

I'm currently trying to setup my website for translation.
My website is currently in French and I would like to translate it in English. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Put the `{% load i18n %}` tag at the top of the html
2. Put a field up for translation with `{% trans "Services" %}`
3. In settings.py:

I've added `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to the
    middleware classes list.

I've also set the current language to
    french with `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'`

I've specified which languages are available with

```
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('Anglais')),
    ('fr', ugettext('Français')),
)
```

I've turned on I18N translation with `USE_I18N = True`

I've specified where I want the localization files to be

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)
```

---

When I run `django-admin.py makemessages -l en -v3`, here's what I get:

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Ajitech\ajitech-website> django-admin.py makemessages -l en -v3
examining files with the extensions: .txt and .html
ignoring directory .git
ignoring file settings.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechRoot\__pycache__
ignoring file urls.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechRoot\__pycache__
ignoring file wsgi.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechRoot\__pycache__
ignoring file __init__.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechRoot\__pycache__
ignoring file __init__.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechWebsite\migrations\__pycache__
ignoring file admin.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechWebsite\__pycache__
ignoring file models.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechWebsite\__pycache__
ignoring file views.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechWebsite\__pycache__
ignoring file __init__.cpython-34.pyc in .\AjitechWebsite\__pycache__
processing file AjitechData.sqlite3 in .
processing file __init__.py in .\AjitechRoot
processing file settings.py in .\AjitechRoot
processing file urls.py in .\AjitechRoot
processing file wsgi.py in .\AjitechRoot
processing file __init__.py in .\AjitechWebsite
processing file admin.py in .\AjitechWebsite
processing file __init__.py in .\AjitechWebsite\migrations
processing file models.py in .\AjitechWebsite
processing file tests.py in .\AjitechWebsite
processing file views.py in .\AjitechWebsite
processing file Runserver.ps1 in .
processing file db.sqlite3 in .
processing file manage.py in .
processing file base.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file changelists.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file dashboard.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file forms.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file ie.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file login.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file rtl.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file widgets.css in .\static\static-only\admin\css
processing file changelist-bg.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file changelist-bg_rtl.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file default-bg-reverse.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file default-bg.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file deleted-overlay.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file move_vertex_off.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img\gis
processing file move_vertex_on.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img\gis
processing file icon-no.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon-unknown.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon-yes.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_addlink.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_alert.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_calendar.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_changelink.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_clock.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_deletelink.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_error.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_searchbox.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file icon_success.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file inline-delete-8bit.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file inline-delete.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file inline-restore-8bit.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file inline-restore.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file inline-splitter-bg.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file nav-bg-grabber.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file nav-bg-reverse.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file nav-bg-selected.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file nav-bg.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file selector-icons.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file selector-search.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file sorting-icons.gif in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file tooltag-add.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file tooltag-arrowright.png in .\static\static-only\admin\img
processing file LICENSE-JQUERY.txt in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file SelectBox.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file SelectFilter2.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file actions.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file actions.min.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file DateTimeShortcuts.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js\admin
processing file RelatedObjectLookups.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js\admin
processing file calendar.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file collapse.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file collapse.min.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file core.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file inlines.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file inlines.min.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file jquery.init.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file jquery.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file jquery.min.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file prepopulate.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file prepopulate.min.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file timeparse.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file urlify.js in .\static\static-only\admin\js
processing file animation.css in .\static\static\css
processing file bootstrap.min.css in .\static\static\css
processing file font-awesome.min.css in .\static\static\css
processing file FontAwesome.otf in .\static\static\fonts
processing file fontawesome-webfont.eot in .\static\static\fonts
processing file fontawesome-webfont.svg in .\static\static\fonts
processing file fontawesome-webfont.ttf in .\static\static\fonts
processing file fontawesome-webfont.woff in .\static\static\fonts
processing file fontawesome-webfont.woff2 in .\static\static\fonts
processing file ajitech-jumbotron-background-color-small.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-jumbotron-background-small.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-jumbotron-background.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-jumbotron-even.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-jumbotron-odd.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-logo-large.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-logo.png in .\static\static\images
processing file ajitech-logo.svg in .\static\static\images
processing file programming.jpg in .\static\static\images\services
processing file username-normal.png in .\static\static\images\team
processing file ajitech.js in .\static\static\js
processing file bootstrap.min.js in .\static\static\js
processing file jquery-2.1.3.min.js in .\static\static\js
processing file less-2.5.0.min.js in .\static\static\js
processing file wow.min.js in .\static\static\js
processing file ajitech-404.less in .\static\static\less
processing file ajitech-utilities.less in .\static\static\less
processing file ajitech.less in .\static\static\less
processing file 404.html in .\static\templates
processing file overview.html in .\static\templates
processing locale en
```

My message to translate is in overview.html, which has been processed by the script (last file processed).

After all this, I expect a .po file to be generated in the locale folder,  containing the "Service" line to be translated to English. However, that is not the case. Is there something I'm missing?

---

Here's my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for AjitechRoot project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '** REDACTED **'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '127.0.0.1' ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'AjitechWebsite',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'AjitechRoot.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'AjitechRoot.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'AjitechData.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
TIME_ZONE = 'Eastern/Canada'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)

ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('Anglais')),
    ('fr', ugettext('Français')),
)


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Template location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/templates'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/static-only')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/static'),
)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I'm using Django 1.8.1.

The makemessages command is called from the root folder of my website, the one where you can find manage.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, I was running a deprecated version of GNU GetText (0.12 to be precise), and makemessages requires version 0.15 or later, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows). I've updated the tool and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), the class LocaleMiddleware has to be located after SessionMiddleware and before CommonMiddleware in the variable MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. For example:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

Moreover, at least in Django 1.8 I had to create manually the locale directory inside every app I wanted to get translated.

You should also use the function ugettext_lazy() in your settings.py file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Built-in template context processors [were moved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) from django.core.context_processors to django.template.context_processors in Django 1.8, so you should use:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
)
```

However, it is not necessary to override the [default settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) because the i18n context processor is included by default.

Take into account that TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) since Django 1.8.

Comment: Still no luck, I get the same result with these changes. I already had created the locale folder at the root of my project (in the manage.py folder). Thank you for your time though

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Are you using Django templates or Jinja2? From which folder do you run the makemessages command?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.8.1 and the command is called from the root folder, where you can find manage.py

Comment: I've found out my issue and solved the problem. Have an upvote though, to thank you for not giving up on me :D

Comment: Glad you finally did it! It was clear that we were missing some little detail. Thanks for the upvote @Msonic!